# JUnit Mockito using a static class final variable

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing J-unit with Mockito for a Utility class. I have another class for Constants and there is a constant used as below :

```
@Singleton
public class Constants {
    public static boolean convertStringtoBoolean(String val) {
        return true/false;
    }
}

public class MyConstants extends Constants {
    public static final boolean flagValue = convertStringtoBoolean("someValue");
}
```

It reads the `flagValue` when the application is running in an `env`. So this is `env` specific.
Now I have a `if() condition` with this flag value in my class. And I want to control this boolean value.

Can I do that ? If yes how can I achieve that. This is my method where I am using it :

```
public void myMethod(String, Int) {
    if(MyConstant.flagValue){
         then do something;
    } else {
         do this;
    }    
}
```

Below is the test method I am trying to write :

```
public void testMyMethod(){
    Constants const = Mockito.mock(Constants.class);
    Mockito.when(const.convertStringtoBoolean("some-value")).thenReturn(false);

    myMethod(someString, someInt);

}
```

But I am getting the below error :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

**UPDATE :** Provided more info on the code and error.

Comment: Can you use `mockito-inline`? If not, then convert the myMethod to accept a boolean and test that without the state.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock static methods with Mockito. The test is telling you that your code is not as testable as it may be. Your class `MyConstants` should have a method

```
public boolean isFlagSet() {
  return flagValue;
}
```

and the other class needs to get `MyConstants` injected

```
class OtherClass {
  private final MyConstants myConstants;

  OtherClass(
    MyConstants myConstants
  ) {
    this.myConstants = myConstants;
  }

  public void myMethod(String, Int) {
    if(myConstant.isFlagSet()){
      then do something;
    } else {
      do this;
    }
  }    
}
```

In your test you can create a mock/stub of `MyConstants`, inject it into `OtherClass` and your test `testMyMethod` will work.

Comment: Your statement, "You cannot mock static methods with Mockito", is no longer entirely accurate. See https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your actual question:

In your code,

```
public void testMyMethod(){
    Constants const = Mockito.mock(Constants.class);
    Mockito.when(const.convertStringtoBoolean("some-value")).thenReturn(false);

    myMethod(someString, someInt);

}
```

The variable `const` does nothing. Since `convertStringtoBoolean` is a static method, your call `const.convertStringtoBoolean("some-value")` is the same as `Constants.convertStringtoBoolean("some-value")`. The variable `const` is not used at all, other than to signify its type.

To mock a static method, you need to use the `mockStatic` method (which is enabled by the mockito-inline dependency):

```
try (MockStatic mock = mockStatic(Constants.class)) {
    mock.when(() -> Constants.convertStringtoBoolean("some-value")).thenReturn(false);
    
    myMethod(someString, someInt);
    
    //assert(...)/verify(...);
}
```

However, stepping back and looking at your issue from a higher level, I think you may be using the anti-pattern of inheritance for use of a method. Your `Constants` class should used just for constants. The static method should be  in another utility method that should be final, have a private constructor, and designed purely as a utility method. Also, it would be best to use dependency injection and construct your instance by passing to the constructor the environment that it depends on.